# Can Breeze.js auto-generate metadata for non-database entities?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-5, breeze, single-page-application

I'm building a Single Page App with Breeze.js, WebApi and Entity Framework.

I would like to have the `EFContextProvider`-niceness of auto-generated metadata, but do not want to expose my DB model to the client.

I imagine having a bunch of client-specific DTOs. Can I get Breeze/EF to generate metadata for these entities?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not yet, but we are working on publishing some guidance on how you might do this yourself and perhaps with some examples.

Comment: Thanks, looking forward to hearing more :)

Comment: Thats definitely in Need here. DTOs are essential for hiding the databaselayer from the client layer.